# Android: dynamically Creating a list of objects each with their own buttons and EditTexts

Tags: android

I want to dynamically add rows to a linear layout where each row would have 2 buttons and 2 edittexts. I am not sure the best way to organize this. I had the idea to creating a class for each row with the buttons and edittexts in them but FindViewByID doesn't work that way. The other thought was to include an instance of a layout for each object but I am not sure the best way to efficiently access the buttons in the layout without creating action listeners for, if I had 10 objects, 20 buttons and 20 edittexts. Is it possible to use an array of included layouts and add them as I need them If I do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a layout file for the row, use LayoutInflator to create it dynamically, and create the listeners for each.  I don't think the overhead will kill you.

If its a variable number of rows, you should do this in a list view with a custom ArrayAdaptor, and recycle your layouts.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View yourRowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.yourrowfile, null);
yourRowView.findByViewId(R.id.firstButton). setOnClickListener(//blah blah blah

((ViewGroup)findByViewId(R.id.yourParentContainer)).addView(yourRowView);
```

The LayoutInflator inflates layouts from your xml layout definitions.  Usually in an Activity you just pass R.layout.[whatever] to setContentView, but if you want to dynamically create a view and add it, you can use the code above (or similar).  Be aware, to fill the boxes and trigger the buttons, you need to call findByViewId ON THE VIEW.  I often make the mistake to call that method on the activity by accident (force of habit).

To make a list view with a custom UI, its conceptually similar, but the plumbing is a little more complex, yet widely described.  Here's an example:

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: uhh okay, is there a way to dumb that down a little bit. I'm just starting out. I should create the layout of the buttons and editTexts and then use an inflator to add them, correct? How will I access the individual layouts with an inflator?

Comment: I tried you code and the .from syntax is incorrect. I am running 2.3.3 and from what I've found on the internet it is different than previous versions. Do you know how to do it on the newer platform?

Comment: I'd be shocked if that didn't work.  Depends where you're calling it from.  Post code?  If you're inside an anonymous function, you need to prepend 'this' with the Activity class name like MyActivity.this.
That form is still available here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from(android.content.Context)

However, you can do it the hard way and use this:
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

You'll need a reference to 'context', but since that's what 'this' is pointing to, same problem.